# Does the indigo pink theme get completely initialized when running ng add @angular/material and scss?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

When running `ng add @angular/material` it asks what css framework and theme we want.  I selected indigo-pink and scss.  Do we need to do anything else, or do the material components just get the theme applied automatically?

With normal css (No CSS framework) we add this to `styles.css`:

```
@import “~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css”;
```

I'm assumed would Angular just does this automatically now since the CSS theme is included in `angular.json`, however I'm not seeing styles being rendered automatically.  Here's a screenshot of the stepper:

[image]

Tried adding the below to `styles.scss` but the error is still there:

```
    /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
    @import '~@angular/material/theming';
    // Plus imports for other components in your app.

    // Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
    // have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
    // Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
    @include mat-core();
```

## Update

I generated a brand new project and tried the minimal setup I have above with the same choices and now it works, so I probably made a small mistake somewhere.  I'll leave this up in case anyone comes across a similar issue.

Comment: Yeah I noticed the same thing with a fresh ng add material. Haven't seen any issues that would make me believe it isn't being fully initialized. In the past, I would get a warning in the console if I didn't import a prebuilt theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were an scss file there might be a difference because there might be variables in it that you would want to reference in your styles file.  Since it is a css file the only difference could possibly be the order.

If you have rules in styles.scss they could be overridden by the indigo pink styles but this would happen *only if* indigo pink comes after your style sheet in angular.json.

Comment: So I got a little further along developing and what I suspected turns out to be true - which is that no  styles are rendering at all ... Thoughts?  I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: I assume you are using some material components in that screenshot?  Have you added the appropriate material modules to your module?  Do you get any errors on the console?  If you inspect an element do you see any material styling at all being applied?

Comment: I just checked the console and it says this: core.js:164 Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: I would think that the schematics would have automatically pulled in the core theme when setting up indigo pink ...

Comment: Updated the question with a new attempt, and it works now, so I probably had some minimal configuration issue in the last one.